# Applying the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization method in order to find an orthonormal basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

> Apply the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization method in order to find an orthonormal basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is generated by the vectors $(1, 0, 1, 1)^T , (1, 1, 0, 0)^T$ and $(0, 0, 1, 1)^T$

$$u_1=(1, 0, 1, 1)^T , u_2=(1, 1, 0, 0)^T , u_3=(0, 0, 1, 1)^T$$

I used the formula $$V_1=\dfrac{u_1}{||u_1||}$$$$V_2=\dfrac{u_2-<u_2V_1>V_1}{||u_2-<u_2V_1>V_1||}$$$$V_3=\dfrac{u_3-<u_3V_2>V_2-<u_3V_1>V_1}{||u_3-<u_3V_2>V_2-<u_3V_1>V_1||}$$

I got the basis as $$V_1=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^T$$$$V_2=\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{7}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)^T$$$$V_3=\left(-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{10}},\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{10}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^T$$

But the answer in the book was$$V_1=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^T$$$$V_2=\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{15}},\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{15}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}\right)^T$$$$V_3=\left(-\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{90}},\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{90}},\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{90}},\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{90}}\right)^T$$

Which answer is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is correct. Note that, in order to compute $v_2$, first you must compute\begin{align}a_2&=u_2-\langle u_2,v_1\rangle v_1\\&=\left(\frac23,1,-\frac13,-\frac13\right)^T.\end{align}So,\begin{align}v_2&=\frac{a_2}{\|a_2\|}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{15}}\left(2,,3,-1,-1\right).\end{align}

Comment: But when I took dot product of $V_1\cdot V_2$ I got $0$.

Comment: @philip Yes, it is $0$. And… ? What do you deduce from that?

Comment: Since $V_1\cdot V_2=0$ they are orthogonal. I think I made a mistake in calculating $V_3$

Comment: @philip It's not enough that they're orthogonal. The exercise tells you to find an orthonormal basis of a certain vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ by a specific algorithm. And the second vector you got was not the one that you would get if you applied that algorithm.

Comment: Carlos Santos Sir, can you please explain step by step how to solve this.

Comment: @philip Isn't that what I did in my answer when I computed $v_2$?

Comment: How did you calculated $||a_2||$

Comment: \begin{align}\|a_2\|&=\left\|\left(\frac23,\frac33,-\frac13,-\frac13\right)\right\|\\&=\frac13\|(2,3,-1,-1)\|\\&=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}.\end{align}

Comment: But from [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2859844/572932](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2859844/572932) answer I thought that whenever $V_1\cdot V_2$= $V_2\cdot V_3$= $V_3\cdot V_1=0$ then my basis are correct.

Comment: @philip That’s a necessary, but not sufficient condition.

Comment: @amd So, to verify whether my basis are correct or not I should check for orthogonality right?

Comment: Indeed you should, but for your incorrect solution $V_2\cdot V_3\ne0$.